# ListView inside ListView show wrong item Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a ListView with comments items and every comment has a new ListView with comment reply, I've used Firebase and when I replied to comment it is showing the wrong text on ListView but in console correct text is printed. When I go back and come again it shows the correct value. Watch [video](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pixz-92afa.appspot.com/o/Issues%2FScreen%20Recording%202020-01-14%20at%2011.36.31%20AM.mov?alt=media&token=1619e23b-4c97-4fe6-97cd-4e2aab4cdcf1) for clarification.

```
 Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
             child: StreamBuilder(
             stream: getCommentReply(listMessage[index]['id']),
             builder: (context, snapshot) {
               if (!snapshot.hasData) {
               return Center(child: Text(''));
               }
               var listReplyMessage = snapshot.data.documents;
               return Padding(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                     child: commentsReplyItems(listReplyMessage,
                     snapshot, listMessage[index]['id']));
        }))

  Widget commentsReplyItems(
    var listMessage, AsyncSnapshot snapshot, String commentID) {

       return CommentReplay(
       listMessage, snapshot, commentID, widget.currentUser, widget.postID);
 }




 Stream<QuerySnapshot> getCommentReply(String msgID) {
   Stream<QuerySnapshot> _query = Firestore.instance
    .collection('Posts')
    .document(widget.postID)
    .collection('Comments')
    .document(msgID)
    .collection('Reply')
    .orderBy('created_at', descending: true)
    .limit(2)
    .snapshots();

    return _query;
 }
```

Comment Reply Item

```
class CommentReplay extends StatefulWidget {
List<dynamic> listMessage;
AsyncSnapshot snapshot;
String commentID;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
String postID;

CommentReplay(this.listMessage, this.snapshot, this.commentID,
  this.currentUser, this.postID);

 @override
 _CommentReplayState createState() => _CommentReplayState();
}

class _CommentReplayState extends State<CommentReplay> {
  var _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      key: _key,
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: widget.snapshot.data.documents.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, position) {
      //print(position);
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
           Text(
                                  widget.listMessage[position['commentText'],
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      color: Color(0xff0D0E15)),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,

                                )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a code snippet of your own code. 
It's not good practice on StackOverFlow to redirect to a video for the reference code of the question...

Comment: In order for us to help, you must provide relavent code snippet.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: I am not sure this is going to fix, but try to add a Key to the container in the second itemBuilder (the one with replies).

Comment: Thanks but same result

Comment: Does the error occurs also if you just use `itemCount: widget.snapshot.data.documents.length` without the check of lenght > 2? Does it show all the comments in that case? I mean, I saw the video and I understand why it's there, but could you in case just try to build listview with all the comments?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove this condition but I already set limit is 2, please check latest code

Answer (score 5):

after looking your code i find to use the key with comment reply Container solve your problem.

I used it like below and its working

```
 return ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    controller: _replayController,
    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        key: Key(listMessage[index]['id']),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
        child: Row()
   )
    });
```